# DXA_Live\BinaryData disk usage - we have to inform our hosting partner

Tags: dxa, sites-9, dxa2.2

Till now we had published the (non DXA) website files on disk.

With the DXA application content will come from broker database and we can expect a lot of write/reads
to folders for example BinaryData\tcm-96\media.
We have to inform our hosting partner for how many time this will be used (compared with non DXA).

**My questions are:**

- Where is BinaryData..\ used for (images, pages, content) ?
- What load can we expect on folder BinaryData... ?
- Is it more then once? How is this handles in the DXA Framework ?
- Will there be more then .. % load then in the before DXA ?
- Who is deleting old (cashed) files from BinaryData.. ?

Thanks in advanced for anwering.

Comment: welcome to Tridion stack exchange , can you please specify your tridion version and DXA version

Comment: tridion 9 with DXA2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Where is BinaryData..\ used for (images, pages, content) ?

  - The `BinaryData` folder structure is a FileSystem cache for so-called *Static Content Items*. That is: binaries, assets and configuration files (stored as Binary in the database). This file system cache results in much better performance and less load on the CD database.
- What load can we expect on folder BinaryData... ?

  - Each incoming request binary data will result in a file read. File writes are much less frequent (only when a new binary is published or an existing one is updated).
  - DXA includes HTTP cache headers for the Static Content Items which make the browser cache them client-side and not request the same item multiple times.
- Is it more then once? How is this handles in the DXA Framework ?

  - I don’t understand this question
- Will there be more then .. % load then in the before DXA ?

  - Load on the BinaryData cache will be similar to load on the File System when binaries are published to File System directly.
- Who is deleting old (cashed) files from BinaryData.. ?

  - It is best to schedule a job which removes old files on a regular basis.

Comment: Rick thanks for the response, I guess for question number 3 - i think what i understand is -       Requests for other assets, such as configuration, images, CSS, or script files, are handled by a    Static Content (HTTP) Module, which retrieves them directly from the Content Provider.